# The distance between i and j by the number of sentences that separate the two noun phrase

Tags: python

The distance between i and j by the number of sentences that separate the two noun phrase. First I searched for i and j, and now how to count the number of stop marks between them. The regex I used not find the stop marks.
Here is the dataset:

```
در
همین
حال
،
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="ne" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
نجیب
الله
خواجه
عمری
,
</coref>
<coref coref_coref_class="set_0" coref_mentiontype="np" markable_scheme="coref" coref_coreftype="ident">
سرپرست
وزارت
تحصیلات
عالی
افغانستان
</coref>
گفت
که
در
سه
ماه
گذشته
.
```

Now how to count for each i and j, the number of sentence between them, if they are in the same sentence it should return 0, else 1,2.

```
i_NP = []
j_NP = []
find_coref = re.findall(r'<coref.*?coref_coref_class="set.*?>(.*?)</coref>[.!?]', read_dataset, re.S)
coref_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('\n', ' '), find_coref))
for i in range(0,len(coref_list)-1,2):
    i_NP.append(coref_list[i])
    j_NP.append(coref_list[i+1])
count = 0
    for dot in i_NP and j_NP:
        if dot == '.':
            count = count +1



print(i_NP, j_NP)
```

Comment: ... and your problem is?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, I mentioned that how to count for each i and j, the number of sentence between them, if they are in the same sentence it should return 0, else 1

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem of distance between `i` and `j`. First I count the number of sentences in the dataset and then test if both variable based on the index that gets from `while loop`.

```
def distance_feature():
    tok = sent_tokenize(str(read_dataset))
    ln = len(tok)
    i = 1
    k = 1
    while i<=ln:
        if k == i:
            if any(elem in (i_NP[k-1] and j_NP[k-1]) for elem in read_dataset):
                i = i + 1
                k = k + 1
                return 0
            else:
                return 1
```